# Summing values in a list

Tags: python

I want to add values of same ids

For ex: In below data, '6' have two values `('6', 0.8556180596351624)` and `('6', 0.864041805267334)`.

I want to sum over values `('6', 1.7196598649025)`

```
[('6', 0.8556180596351624), ('10', 0.8263003826141357), ('3', 0.8221487998962402), ('5', 0.8209285140037537), ('21', 0.8116759061813354), ('13', 0.798694372177124), ('16', 0.7894450426101685), ('17', 0.788898766040802), ('2', 0.7756567001342773), ('9', 0.7618461847305298), ('6', 0.864041805267334)
```

How could I do that? suggestions please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `collections.defaultdict` to categorize the items based on their first value, then sum the second value for duplicate ones:

```
In [22]: from collections import defaultdict

In [24]: d = defaultdict(int)

In [25]: lst = [('6', 0.8556180596351624), ('10', 0.8263003826141357), ('3', 0.8221487998962402), ('5', 0.8209285140037537), ('21', 0.8116759061813354), ('13', 0.798694372177124), ('16', 0.7894450426101685), ('17', 0.788898766040802), ('2', 0.7756567001342773),   ]

In [26]: for i, j in lst:
   ....:     d[i] += j
   ....:     

In [27]: d.items()
Out[27]: 
[('10', 0.8263003826141357),
 ('13', 0.798694372177124),
 ('21', 0.8116759061813354),
 ('17', 0.788898766040802),
 ('16', 0.7894450426101685),
 ('3', 0.8221487998962402),
 ('2', 0.7756567001342773),
 ('5', 0.8209285140037537),
 ('6', 1.7196598649024963),
 ('9', 0.7618461847305298)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want this for all unique values, I'd use a `defaultdict()`:

```
import collections
d = ... your list ...
cd = collections.defaultdict(int)
for key, value in d: cd[key] += value
print cd["6"]
```

This prints 1.7196598649024963.